# Strange behaviour of extern in c

Tags: c

I am surprised with the following behaviour of extern.

When I run this

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
int a=20;
```

**OUTPUT:** 20(in gcc Linux 32-bit,which seems OK)

But when I declare the variable `a` inside `main()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int a;
    int a=20;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
extern.c: In function ‘main’:
extern.c:5:9: error: declaration of ‘a’ with no linkage follows extern declaration
extern.c:4:16: note: previous declaration of ‘a’ was here
```

Why I am getting the error now after changing the scope of `a` from global to local?Why it now doesn't allow redeclaration of `a` ,whereas it allowed in previous case.

Comment: I have already mentioned this yesterday to someone else, but I honestly don't understand why askers think that they are being downvoted because people don't know the answer. It's not that. It's just that bad questions (i. e. those which don't show research effort, which are spam, etc.) are being downvoted. I would downvote a question like "why does `"foo"[0] = 'a';` segfault?", although I know the answer very well, and I know it instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are telling to the compiler: "hey, I have this variable called `a` that is defined somewhere else.", and then you use it. That's fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
int a=20;
```

In the second example, you are also telling to the compiler that there is somewhere in the program a variable called `a` you want to use, and then you declare a new variable with the same name on your stack. That does not make much sense and the compiler says 2 things: can't find any declaration of variable `a` in the program and variable `a` already exists (if you fix the first error, it will).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    extern int a;
    int a=20;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

When you declare a global variable, its memory is allocated when the program is launched (it's in the binary file and mapped in memory). When you declare a local variable, the memory is allocated on the stack, during the execution of the function. You can't refer with extern to a variable that does not exist yet.

Comment: The compiler doesn't say that it "can't find any declaration of variable `a`" — it says that the previous declaration and the new one are incompatible (the note following the error simply points to the previous declaration for reference). Also, it's not true that you can't refer with `extern` to a variable that does not exist yet — that is precisely the purpose of `extern`. What you can't have are incompatible declaration and definition, one `extern` and other automatic.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I understand what you are saying but it's just a misunderstanding, I should come back and rephrase with a sentence less ambiguous. By not existing yet I meant when you are executing the program, I am not referring to the compilation phase.

Comment: That is true, but then it doesn't apply to the OP's code, where the variable `a` exists just fine, but with incompatible storage class, as the compiler reports.

Comment: It looks like I downvoted  your answer accidentally and can't fix it now.

Answer (score 7):

The point of an `extern` declaration is to tell the compiler about a global variable or function used by multiple compilation units (`.c` files), but defined and allocated in a single compilation unit. The `extern` declaration is placed in a header file included by all units, and a single compilation unit contains the actual definition, therefore seeing both.

Your first example is legal C: you are *declaring* that `a` will refer to an externally defined variable, and then proceed to *define* that variable in the current compilation unit. Normally the `extern` declaration would be included from a header file and therefore appear to the compiler on top-level, not inside the function, but the compiler doesn't care either way. In other words, here there is no *redefinition*, only definition following declaration.

Your second example declares `a` to have external linkage, and then proceeds to define it as a local variable in `main`. The declaration and the definition are obviously incompatible - if `a` is a local variable, it cannot be defined and allocated in only one place - it will instead be automatically allocated on the stack every time the function is called. This incompatibility results in the error diagnostic.